# Topological group, which is second category in itself, is a Baire space.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, baire-category

A Baire space is a topological space in which the union of every countable collection of closed sets with empty interior has empty interior.

$G$ is a topological group, if $G$ is of the second category (in itself), then $G$ is Baire space, that is to say, every nonempty open subset of $G$ is of the second category in $G$.

How to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a difference between "the Baire space" and "a Baire space". The tag ([tag:the-baire-space]) is not for the concept of Baire space as used in your post. See the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/the-baire-space/info).

Comment: You can have a look at the proof of [Proposition 2.3.1](https://books.google.com/books?id=VfiOZWY282QC&pg=PA51) in Invariant Descriptive Set Theory By Su Gao. I found it by searching for ["topological group" "baire space"](http://books.google.com/books?q=%22topological+group%22+%22baire+space%22) in Google Books.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak:Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you are able to write a proof based on what you read there, you can post it as an answer to your own question.